# =CONCATENATE() function giving a #VALUE! error (EXCEL 2013)

Tags: excel-formula, string-concatenation, excel-2013

So I was trying out the =CONCATENATE() fn in Excel 2013, because apparently it doesn't yet support the =CONCAT() fn yet. When I put a "," between the 2 cells, it ran just fine. But when I tried to input it as a range (=CONCATENATE(A1:B1)), it gave the #VALUE error. Any ideas as to how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: concatenate(A1,B1) or even =A1&B1

Comment: That is why they created CONCAT.  CONCATENATE requires distinct single entries and will not accept ranges or arrays like CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the following:

`=A1&","&B1`

TEXTJOIN would also be helpful, but unfortuantely not available in 2013.